# Android Annotations rest error handling

Tags: java, android, json, android-annotations

Problem is, how to handle unexpected json response from server, this should make the question clearer:

ApiService interface:

```
@Rest(
    converters = MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class,
    interceptors = AuthInterceptor.class,
    responseErrorHandler = MyErrorHandler.class)
public interface ApiService {
  @Get("http://192.168.1.5:3000" + "/balance")
  Balance getBalance();
  ...
}
```

MyErrorHandler class relevant parts

```
@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    switch (response.getStatusCode()) {
        case OK:
        case CREATED:
            return false;
        default:
            return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    switch (response.getStatusCode()) {
        case BAD_REQUEST:
            Log.d(TAG, "handleError: bad request");
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "handleError: Default");
            break;
    }
}
```

MainActivity relevant part (this is where its used)

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getBalance();
}

@Background
void getBalance() {
    showBalance(apiService.getBalance());
}
// show balance is accessing Balance fields and showing it on screen
```

This works good when server returns what its supposed to return, but when it doesnt(e.g it returns error code 400 and json with keys that are not in Balance class) app crashes because Json parser cant parse the response.

I could wrap showBalance() in try catch, but if there are more usages of ApiService's getBalance() somewhere else, I would have to do that for all of them.
Is there a way to break flow of application from MyErrorHandler when it detects error code from server

Comment: does `error handling` ring any bell?

Comment: What can I do in handleError() to prevent the app from trying to convert response to Balance object, currently how it is, it will detect error has happened and it will still try to convert json to Balance

Comment: No, I mean that you should write your code with assumption things can go wrong i.e. SQL query failed (for any reason), HTTP request failed (for any reason). Once you got that, you will not be crashing because of failure of intermediate steps because you will be ready for that case. This is what your approach lacks now

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, I was using ResponseErrorHandler, switching to RestErrorHandler solved it, there I was able to successfully catch exception and stop it from trying to convert 'unexpected' json.

I'm sorry if I poorly explained the problem, hope this helps someone